# DmlExecutionException: Update failed.first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found

Tags: dmlexception, duplicate-value

I understand DUPLICATE_VALUE DML Exception on insert of a record which is already existing However, I am observing this issue for an update on the existing record.
When I find an existing contact record, I try to update the contact with few field including a new Account Id.
This results in error. Any lead could help.

Comment: Can you a share a code snippet with which you are getting this error?

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please see [ask] for getting the most from the community